# template metaprogramming problem

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

```
template <int p>    
bool FComapare (Node *lId, Node* rId)    
{    
    if(lId->getDiff(p) < rId->getDiff(p))
        return true;
    else if(lId->getDiff(p) == rId->getDiff(p))
    {
        if(lId->getLT() < rId->getLT())
            return true;
        else if(lId->getLT() == rId->getLT())
            return (lId->getTFG() < rId->getTFG());
    } 
    return false;
}

vector<set<Node*, bool (*)(Node*,Node*) > > m_F;

for (int i = 0;i < partNum; ++i)
{
    //This doesn`t workbecause of  const problem...
    set<Node *, bool (*)(Node*,Node*) > f(&FComapare<i>);
    m_F.push_back(f);
}
```

I am getting following error

> `error C2664:
>       'std::set<_Kty,_Pr>::set(bool (__cdecl
>       *const &)(Node *,Node *))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool
>       (__cdecl *)(Node *,Node *)' to 'bool
>       (__cdecl *const &)(Node *,Node *)' 1> 
>       with 1>        [ 1>
>
>       _Kty=Node *, 1>            _Pr=bool (__cdecl *)(Node *,Node *) 1>        ]
>        Reason: cannot convert from
>       'overloaded-function' to 'bool
>       (__cdecl *const )(Node *,Node *)' 1>
>
>       None of the functions with this name
>       in scope match the target type`

How can I solve the problem and get the same functionality?
How do I define correctly

```
vector<set<Node*, bool (*)(Node*,Node*) > > m_F;
```

Thanks

Comment: "How can I solve the problem and get the same functionality?" - What functionality? You forgot to tell us exactly what functionality you want in the first place. What end goal are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable for the non-type argument.

Instead of a template function, try a function object that stores the value of `i`.

```
class FCompare
{
    int p;
public:
    FCompare(int p): p(p) {}
    bool operator()(const Node *lId, const Node* rId) const {...}
};

set<Node *, FCompare > f((FCompare(i)));
```

Comment: set<Node *, FCompare >
it doesn`t compile

Comment: vector<set<Node*, bool (*)(Node*,Node*) > > m_F;
so how can I define set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Template parameters should be known at compile time.
In your case you are trying to using a local variable to instantiate a template function that is wrong.

I suppose the best solution is don't use a template, just create a class with operator() that will do the same as FComapare() and store the p as a class member.

Answer (score 1):

Template arguments need to be known at compile time. You can't use runtime values as template arguments.

Since there is no reason that `p` needs to be a template parameter in this case, this isn't a problem though. You can just put the logic of `FCompare` into the `operator()` of a class, which has `p` as a member variable and then pass an instance of that class as the argument to `set`'s constructor.

Comment: How can I define m_F in this case?